# What is difference between it and that?

Tags: differences, that

every time I speak I'm confused about using it or that. For example I want to say: `I'll see that`. and I don't know what happen if I say: `I'll see it`. Can you please describe for me with some examples. Thanks.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22it+or+that%22

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for reference but that is answer just about  a special sentence and i asked about different scenarios. I want to know why we should (or better) use one of them  with some examples and a good reason for each one.

Comment: @mplungjan I read the off-topic from help center and i didn't understand why this question is? Please advise me as a newbie in this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many situations either can be used.

But where you want to give special emphasis to the thing in question ***'that'*** is more appropriate.

For example, imagine a conversation where someone asks 'Can you play football in the rain?'. The answer would be 'Yes'. But then they ask 'But what if the pitch is covered in a foot of water?' The answer would be 'Well you certainly cannot play if ***that*** happens'; meaning ***that*** situation specifically, as opposed to a simple rain shower.

***That*** is used where you want to draw attention to something specific. Though in some UK dialects, most notably in East Anglia, ***that*** replaces ***it*** much of the time.

Comment: Thanks man. So if I understood well, you mean there is not obvious difference between them except emphasis or some dialect, is it right?

Comment: @QMaster From my answer you will see that where you are emphasising something specific ***that*** is quite definitely the word you need.